# why can "for in" use const in JS?

Tags: javascript

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3]

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { // can't use const
  console.log(i, arr[i]);
}

for (const i in arr) { // const is ok
  console.log(i, arr[i]);
}
```

Why can "for in" use const but "for" can't?

Comment: In the first case, the loop variable is mutated (i.e. it exists external to the scope of the loop body). In the second case, an entirely new `i` is supplied for each loop iteration, so no mutation is required. FYI `for(const x of ...` also allows for `const` loop variable.

Comment: Try doing `i++` inside the `for..in` loop

Answer (score 5):

You can't use `const` in the first loop because of `i++` which will reassign the variable `i`.

In the `for in` loop, `i` can be a `const` because it is defined for each iteration.

Comment: he used `var` not `const` or `let`, `var` goes at last element `3`, so output must be `333`, right?

Answer (score 1):

in the `const element in arr` the element is the same as element in the `const element = arr[i]` in the classical forloop. It is a constant variable with local scope, so it is declared and destroyed in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

A quote from this article (https://medium.com/@mautayro/es6-variable-declaration-for-loops-why-const-works-in-a-for-in-loop-but-not-in-a-normal-a200cc5467c2) says:

"What about using const in a for…in or a for…of loop though?
[image: example for in]

Weird, it looks like this works!

Upon deeper inspection of these types of for loops, it seems that they create a new block scope with each iteration. That would mean that each new index is actually a new variable within a new scope & our constant is never reassigned."

This article describes it pretty good: https://medium.com/@mautayro/es6-variable-declaration-for-loops-why-const-works-in-a-for-in-loop-but-not-in-a-normal-a200cc5467c2

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment:

> In the first case, the loop variable is mutated (i.e. it exists external to the scope of the loop body). In the second case, an entirely new `i` is supplied for each loop iteration, so no mutation is required.

However, the choice of block-scoped/function-scoped (`let`/`const` vs `var`) declaration has an impact on the way that captured loop variables are treated. Run the code below and notice how using `var` causes output that most users would not expect.

```js
const captured = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
  captured.push(() => console.log(i));
}

for (let i = 2; i < 4; ++i) {
  captured.push(() => console.log(i));
}

for (const i of [4, 5]) {
  captured.push(() => console.log(i));
}

for (var i of [6, 7]) {
  captured.push(() => console.log(i));
}

for (let i of [8, 9]) {
  captured.push(() => console.log(i));
}

captured.forEach(v => v());
```